# Directional audiophile fuses

Tags: audio, fuses

There are some "audiophile fuses" in the market, and the manufacturers claim that they are directional.

Here are some examples:

- [HiFi-Tuning](http://www.6moons.com/audioreviews/net/net.html)
- [Isoclean](http://www.6moons.com/audioreviews/isoclean3/fuses.html)

Here is a quote from a fuse review (yep...):

- "After a few hours I received a reply from Mr. Stein with a question that turned the dance around. He asked if I installed each fuse using the directional arrow shown on the fuse logo. He informed me these fuses are directional and must be installed in that manner to work correctly." 
  [A fuse review at the Stereo Times](http://www.stereotimes.com/acc051311.shtml)

Now, my question is how can AC fuses be directional, given the nature of AC?

Comment: Some devices (very few) are directional when it comes to audio. Fuses are not one of them.

Comment: They have to be aligned magnetically with the earth and switched into reverse on a leap year too.

Comment: They aren't directional and won't improve signal performance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is much snake-oil around audio equipment. I am consistently amazed at how many new ways can be found to part the gullible from their money. Directional fuses is a new one on me! I so wish I had the imagination and lack of morals to allow me to make money like this.

There is one way you can actually make fuses directional, and that's put a different size of connector on each end. You can also print an arrow on them, put a note in the datasheet, and charge 100x more than for the old bi-directional ones.

The fuse comprises 20mm of the 200km path from generator to amplifier. Mains carries RF interference on it, with added 1500v spikes. It's worth adding an RF filter, it's worth some TVS over-voltage protection diodes. Is it worth silver plating 0.00001% of the generator to amplifier circuit? I think not. I notice one of the fuse reviewers removed the fixed cord and replaced it with an IEC socket. Do you know what the contact material is on those?

A friend once asked me if there would be any audible difference between wiring speakers with 160 strand oxygen-free linear crystal copper speaker wire, or 4mm2 twin'n'earth. I said yes. If you use the twin'n'earth, you will have much more money left over to buy music.

Comment: This one is actually filled with snake-oil: http://www.audio-magic.com/Prod-NanoFuse.html ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Slow blow fuses are indeed directional. They are (the fuse wire) slightly thicker at one end (hence the slow blow).

Fast blow fuses are even dimensions from end-to-end - therefore these aren't directional.

There's no way around it with slow blow - as all equipment is different with regards to what way is pointing what - testing what way around is purely and simply experimental.

No such worries with fast blows - the only thing to think about really - is picking a high enough rating to take into account the initial switch on "in rush". Which can be anything up to double of the components's max output wattage.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: What about the asymmetrical fuse wire, if they indeed have such a thing (I have my doubts), makes the fusing action dependent on... anything to do with orientation? I fail to see any physical phenomenon that would cause any directional effect. Fuses, both slow and fast blow, are used on AC all the time with no negative effects.

Comment: Unfortunately AC current could not care less which way you put in a fuse. If you think it matters, please link to a fuse datasheet which says it does matter.

Comment: @StuGTodd A slow-blow fuse... blows slowly? They use a thicker-gauge (higher-mass) wire than fast-blow fuses, but it's coiled to raise its thermal impedance to ambient, so that heat builds up over time in the wire, eventually melting it. A fast-blow fuse uses a straight wire of a thinner gauge, so that it heats up and cools down faster (lower mass and lower thermal impedance to ambient).

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted after being flagged (or other reasons). [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. Failure to follow the rules will have consequences, so please stay civil. Thanks.